# Save input and write it out with DOM - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input

Hello i want to save my input from a html5 page into a var input
and want to display it on an another page..

Here you can see my coding.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method ="post" action="TestJS.html">
            <p>Vorname: <input type="text" id="vorname"></p>
            <p><input value="Send" type="submit"></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
        
   
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing of JavaScript - Language</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
<script>
        
        var input = document.getElementById('vorname').value;
        document.write(input);
        
    </script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Javascript can not access posted values. Use get or localStorage().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `method` attribute to `GET` at  `<form>` element, set `target` attribute of `form` to `"_blank"`. Provide a `name` attribute for `<input>` element to pass query string to an `TestJS.html` `document` at a new `window`.

At `TestJS.html` use `load` event of `window` parse `location.search` with `String.prototype.slice()`, `String.prototype.split()` to retrieve passed query string, then set `.innerHTML` of an element at `TestJS.html`.

```
  <form method="GET" action="TestJS.html" target="_blank">
    <p>Vorname:
      <!-- set `name` attribute at `input` element -->
      <input type="text" name="text" id="vorname">
    </p>
    <p>
      <input value="Send" type="submit">
    </p>
  </form>
```

TestJS.html

```
  <div id="result"></div>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      // parse query string parameters of `location.search` : `?text=<input>`
      var props = location.search.slice(1).split("=");
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =  props[0] + ":" + props[1];
    }
  </script>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/Dq3PE4Xhx3pllIHSpwNy?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can not send values from one page to another with just front end javascript. You need a backend programming language for that. In JavaScript node.js should be able to do it.